# OS X Safari: Toggle Socks Proxy from command line

Tags: safari, command-line, proxy, socks

I need to toggle back and forth between engaging and disengaging a socks proxy within Safari:

> Next open safari and click on "safari" in the top left menu bar to
>   open the drop down menu and then click on preferences. You can do the
>   same thing by pressing CMD+,. Click on the advanced tab and find
>   "Proxies", click "Change Settings". System Preferences should open and
>   you can now select "SOCKS Proxy". You should be setup and if you check
>   google for your IP it should be masked by the address that you're
>   SSH'd into. Note this is system wide and will cover all network
>   communications. You can turn this off by unselecting the SOCKS Proxy.

Is it possible to perform this task with a script?  Bonus round: add button or menu item to Safari UI to execute proxy toggle.   Any feedback to clarify question is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To turn on SOCKS proxy for the network service called Wi-Fi, run

```
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate Wi-Fi on
```

Replace ‘Wi-Fi’ with the name of your network service.
Replace ‘on’ with ‘off’ to turn off the proxy.

Comment: How would this be scripted to: If setsocksfirewallproxystate is not on then set to on else set to off?

Comment: @gatorback 3 years late but `networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxy Wi-Fi` prints the current SOCKS proxy state and related info